# Ionic: IOS simulator does not work for scrolling when code in view-content

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

When I write my horizontal scroll box inside the view-content, it does not work...However if move it out of the view-content, it can work... Does anyone know what's wrong? I guess some css for view-content? However I don't know what's the default code...

Comment: All work fine in browser, but wrong in the IOS simulator...

Answer (score 0):

May be this is due to the double scrolling at same position which you may not able to proper scroll at iOS. We can do the same ar brower because scroll and drag is different in browser.

Comment: do you checked as mentioned above?